# Ford-Fulkerson for irrational capacities

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We know that the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm works for integer capactities but it may loop forever for irrational ones. Is there an algorithm that only alters Ford-Fulkerson slightly but works for irrational values too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See the [Edmonds-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm). Note that Ford-Fulkerson is not really fully defined because it doesn't tell you how to pick an augmenting path. Edmonds-Karp does: always pick a shortest path with available capacity.